# How to get code instead of access token with facebook javasscript login sdk?

Tags: reactjs, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am implementing facebook login in my react website. I am following facebook documentation [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/web)

It's all fine, the only issue is, the response is an access token. I want to receive a one time code, then exchange it for an access token on the server side.

I don't want to manually build the login flow as described [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/manually-build-a-login-flow), which indeed gives you a code, but It includes user redirecting. I prefere the facebook dialog using the javascript sdk.

So, Is there a way to get a one time code using the facebook javascript sdk ?

Comment: No, I don’t think that is possible. The JS SDK provides functionality for the client-side login flow only.

Comment: _“but It includes user redirecting”_ - you could still open the authorization URL in a popup yourself, and then when the user gets redirected back to your return URL inside the popup, pass the code from there to your main window, and close the popup again …

Comment: The popup is a great idea, I will give it a try

Comment: I just have a question regarding the facebook sdk approach. Why do we need the secret key ? We only use the app id to get the access token, we don't use the secret key at all.

Comment: Not sure what you are referring to; the client-side JS SDK does not need the app secret, it would in fact be bad to expose the secret on the client side.